# how many equivalence classes of $f:M\to M$ (that for each $R\in M$ , $f(R)$is the reflexive closure) where $f(R)=f(S)$ exists?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $A=\{1,2,3\}$ , M = $A\times A$ (relations onto A)
Let $f:M\to M$ be function that for each $R\in M$ , $f(R)$is the reflexive closure.
$R,S\in M$ belong to the same equivalence classes $\Leftrightarrow $ $f(R)=f(S)$ 
how many equivalence classes are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: How many reflexive relations on $A$ are there?

Comment: $\[{{2}^{6}}\]$ = 64 <br/>
{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)} , it's the base reflexive <br/>
then i can add up to 6 items (1,2)(1,3)(2,1)(2,3)(3,1)(3,3)

Comment: @Shahar? Yes. And $R$ and $S$ are in the same class if and only if they have the same reflexive closure, so ... ?

Comment: So beacuse there only 64 of diffrent reflexive relations exists,
there are 64 classes?

Comment: @Shahar: That’s right. Each reflexive relation clearly belongs to a different class from each other reflexive relation, so there are at least that many classes. And if $R$ is a relation whose reflexive closure is $S$, then $R$ and $S$ clearly have the same reflexive closure, so they’re in the same class. Thus, there’s one class for each possible reflexive closure, i.e., for each reflexive relation.